# I get app is stopped error when Intent starts

Tags: android, android-intent

I get this error "App is stopped" when I click button(when Intent starts).

Code (Main):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
    EditText et;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview3);

        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                String enbyksayi = et.getText().toString();

                Intent gecis = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sayitahmin.class);
                gecis.putExtra("alinansayi", enbyksayi);
                startActivity(gecis);

            }
        });

     }
}
```

Androidmanifest.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.x_ren.dnm">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application>

</manifest>
```

Sayitahmin.class exist. But I can't go to the sayitahmin class.

Edit: I added AndroidManifest.xml code in the question.

How can I fix this error?

I need your help.

Comment: post the error log with your question

Comment: @KaranMer I don't get error in Android Studio I get this message in telephone : "App is stopped"

Comment: Is your sayitahmin an Activity? have you registered it in your Manifest?

Comment: @VeliGokturk You do get an error message, look in logcat.  If you don't know how to do that, read any of the dozens of tutorials on the web about how to debug android crashes.

Comment: @GabeSechan I get this : Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.x_ren.dnm/com.example.x_ren.dnm.sayitahmin}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Well, have you?

Comment: I added the code in the question @GabeSechan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your activity in AndroidManifest.xml as below sample code.

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".sayitahmin"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>


            </application>
```

Comment: com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device offline
Error while Installing APK I et this error now

Comment: @VeliGokturk That's unrelated to your code, it sounds like your emulator or device needs a reboot.  Or your adb on your machine does.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your manifest file.
    
And check if your sayitahmin is activity or not. If not extend Activity class.